# Any Ideas Why this PHP If / Else Function Doesn't Work?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written two functions to work together on a Wordpress site and am having trouble with the second one.
This is the first function scans the post for an image. If it finds one, it selects as the main image of the site. If there's no image, it defers to a default image.
Here's the function:

```
function main_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches); $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
    if(empty($first_img)){
        //Defines a default image
        $first_img = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";
    }
    return $first_img;
}
```

The code above works fine. For the second part, I'm trying to specify that if the default image was used, the Twitter card should be set to "summary." If another image was found, the Twitter card should be set to "summary_large_image."

Here's the function:

```
function twitter_card() {
    global $post, $posts;
    if ($first_img = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg") {
        echo "summary";
    } else {
        echo "summary_large_image";
    }
}
```

The second function isn't working correctly, as it always returns "summary," whether the listed image is used in the post or not.

If you know why the second function doesn't work, I'd love some insight.

Thanks!

Comment: Note `=` is not the same as `==`

Comment: Also, `$first_img` isn't in the scope of `twitter_card` - it's not part of the `global` statement at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Alex is correct. `if ($first_img = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg")` will always return true because you are assigning "http://www.example.com/image.jpg" to `$first_img` instead of comparing it. Either replace it with `($first_img == "http://www.example.com/image.jpg")` or `($first_img === "http://www.example.com/image.jpg")`

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the = / == issue. Any suggestions on how to build $first_img into the global statement at the beginning of the function? I'm not sure what it would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `==` not `=`.

`==` is comparison
`=` is assignment

As for the `$first_image`, just make it a variable outside the function and then in the function write:

Try this:

```
function twitter_card() { 
    global $post, $posts; 
    if (main_image() == "http://www.example.com/image.jpg") { 
        echo "summary"; 
    } else { 
        echo "summary_large_image"; 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: I correct the == issue and added the lines you suggested, but it returned the "else" statement regardless of which image appeared in the post.

Comment: where is $first_image coming from? a database? the href on the image..?

Comment: It's defined in the first function--the one included at the top of my post here. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: check my code now, i updated it. Since the first function returns $main_image, main_image return being that SHOULD fire summary if function_one returns that. You could also try just echoing out main_image() and making sure it returns that link

Comment: Your code is missing one } at the end, but--with that added--it works perfectly. Moreover, it makes more sense to refer to the main_image part of the function instead of the $first_image part. So, thanks for illustrating that.

Comment: No apology needed. You just salvaged my afternoon. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you use single = sign, the value on the right hand will be assigned to the variable in the left side, and then will be tested.
The result of your code will be always true

the right if will be like this:

```
if ($first_img = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg") { 
        echo "summary"; 
    } else { 
        echo "summary_large_image"; 
    }
```

Another thing to be noted in your code that $first_img is not in the scope.